# Should I just avoid playing 1. e4?

Tags: opening, 1.e4

I can play 1. e4 as long as my opponent does not play 1... c5.

However, I have recently been succeeding in playing 1. d4 despite knowing little to no theory. The only exception is that I am booked up with regards to the King's Indian (as black). I frequently win using it, and even if I play against it I know the plans and strategy, and have no fear playing against 1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6.

Every time my opponent plays 1... c5 in response to 1. e4, I die a little inside. Should I give up 1. e4?

Comment: Is there something in particular about the type of position that results that you don't like?

Comment: `e4` is one of the two most common first moves in chess. Do not give up on it. Instead learn to play against the Sicilian Defense.

Comment: If the sicilian is the only thing bothering you about 1.e4 openings there are several options. Either you book up on the main lines, or you start playing sidelines/anti-sicilians; for instance, 1.e4 c5 2.Nc3 setups are not unsound and tend to work well on the amateur levels. But since it sounds like 1.d4 is working well for you I see no reason to give that up. So keep up the good work with 1.d4, and stick with 1.e4 if you like playing the resulting positions.

Comment: @Scounged Thanks; I really appreciate the advice.

Comment: I vaguely remember the advice (from a master/book author) that "if you fear playing against 1...c5, then you're probably simply not 1.e4 player material" or something along that line. A bit too generalized in my opinion, but I can see the point.

Comment: ...or you could just learn to play against the Sicilian like a real man :p

Comment: If the normal lines feel weird at the moment you could try the Sicilian Alapin. Eventually get good at facing it with normal lines

Comment: @gented related? XD https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/19946/on-1-e4-fischer-and-opening-theory

Comment: @TonyEnnis really? https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/19946/on-1-e4-fischer-and-opening-theory

Comment: @BCLC I don't know what you're trying to express.